# Cannot find insider transaction on chart

Tags: chart, insider-trading

According to [this filing](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/727207/000162828020007895/xslF345X03/wf-form4_158957404422286.xml), this insider bought 89K shares of AXDX on May 13 (presumably all in one buy). But, if I look at the chart for that day, I do not see any big trade like that. There are only two peaks, at about 35K each:

[image: Chart]

I checked charts from other providers, and didn't find anything there either.

So, what am I missing???

Comment: Does it need to be a one lot purchase? The SEC filing is an ownership declaration not a tax form working out gain/loss. I can easily see it as multiple purchases averaging out to the declared valuation.

Comment: According to the filing it was a single purchase. At other times, where the buy was spread over several smaller lots, it was documented as such — like [here](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/727207/000114420418028936/xslF345X03/tv494278_4.xml).

But perhaps he's getting lazier, and is now bundling them all into one (or perhaps the regulations changed, and allow that now).

Comment: Point taken regarding transaction requirements. However the May 13 purchase could have been done as single private sale which wouldn't show up in any public exchange trade volume data.

Comment: Looks like you can bundle multiple transactions, if they're within a dollar (not sure if/when that changed from how it was previously):

_"If the reporting person’s transactions were effected at prices that vary by a dollar or more, the reporting person can nonetheless aggregate groups of transactions occurring within a one dollar price range and report each of those on a separate line."_ ([source](https://www.gibsondunn.com/sec-issues-helpful-new-form-4-and-form-8-k-interpretations/))

Comment: Okay and double checking your linked filing shows footnote 1 (in green): "The price reported in Column 4 is a weighted average price. These shares were purchased in multiple transactions at prices ranging from $9.09 to $9.60, inclusive...."

Answer (score 1):

As posted above, it is allowed (nowadays) to bundle several individual trades into one transaction, and that's why there's no purchase spike visible in the chart.